# Show the minimum value for v

Tags: calculus, fractions

Really struggling with this question...

If $$v=\frac{(L\cdot V1-V1\cdot x+V2\cdot x)\cdot R}{2Lrx-2rx^2+LR}$$

Prove that the minimum values ($x>0$) for $v$ will occur at:

$$x=\frac{L}{V2-V1}\cdot [-V1 \pm \sqrt{V1\cdot V2-\frac{R}{2rL} \cdot (V1-V2)^2}]$$

How do I do this?

I have tried differentiating the equation and setting it to 0, but I end up with a different formula than the one given.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $L,r,R,V_1,V_2$ are constants.

If we set
$$a=-2r,b=2Lr,c=LR,d=R(V_2-V_2),e=RLV_1,$$
we have
$$v=\frac{dx+e}{ax^2+bx+c}\Rightarrow \frac{dv}{dx}=\frac{-dax^2-2eax+dc-eb}{(ax^2+bx+c)^2}.$$

Hence, we have
$$-dax^2-2eax+dc-eb=0$$$$\iff -R(V_2-V_1)(-2r)x^2-2RLV_1(-2r)x+R(V_2-V_1)LR-RLV_1\times 2Lr=0$$
$$\iff (V_2-V_1)x^2+2LV_1x+\frac{(V_2-V_1)LR}{2r}-L^2V_1=0$$
$$\iff x=\frac{-LV_1\pm\sqrt{D}}{V_2-V_1}\tag1$$

where
$$D=L^2V_1^2-(V_2-V_1)\left(\frac{(V_2-V_1)LR}{2r}-L^2V_1\right)$$
$$=L^2\left(V_1^2-\frac{(V_1-V_2)^2R}{2rL}+V_1(V_2-V_1)\right)$$
$$=L^2\left(V_1V_2-\frac{R}{2rL}(V_1-V_2)^2\right).$$
Hence, from $(1)$, we have what you wrote.

P.S. Suppose that $L\gt 0$. Since 
$$D=L^2\left(V_1V_2-\frac{R}{2rL}(V_1-V_2)^2\right),$$
we have
$$\sqrt D=\sqrt{L^2\left(V_1V_2-\frac{R}{2rL}(V_1-V_2)^2\right)}=L\sqrt{V_1V_2-\frac{R}{2rL}(V_1-V_2)^2}.$$

Hence, from $(1)$, we have
$$\begin{align}x&=\frac{-LV_1\pm\sqrt{D}}{V_2-V_1}\\&=\frac{-LV_1\pm L\sqrt{V_1V_2-\frac{R}{2rL}(V_1-V_2)^2}}{V_2-V_1}\\&=\frac{L}{V_2-V_1}\left(-V_1\pm \sqrt{V_1V_2-\frac{R}{2rL}(V_1-V_2)^2}\right).\end{align}$$

Comment: Aha! Thanks for the detailed and fast reply. This helped immensely cheers.

Comment: @Alex30: You are welcome.

Comment: Actually I just came back to this today and was wondering what happens to the L^2 part that you have in the last line for D? Where does it go as it does not appear in the formula I gave. I am a bit confused because I got the same thing as you following your steps. Cheers

Comment: @Alex30: I added a bit. Take a look.

Comment: To complete the discussion, you must check that the values of $x$ are positive, and also that the values computed at the minima do not exceed $v(0)=V1$.

Comment: @mathlove Ahh that makes sense, as its just the combination of the like terms. Doing my head in over something as simple as that lol. Thanks very much.